# NFC - NDEF Push Listener?

Tags: android, nfc

I am currently developing with NFC on android and was curious if there was a listener that existed for when an NDEF record is successfully pushed to another device? (If yes, how it might be implemented)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to examine https://f-droid.org/wiki/page/org.ndeftools.boilerplate

I've used it before in a personal project, it was painless to use. You can simply extend NfcTagWriterActivity, which has all kinds of callbacks (one of which is `writeNdefSuccess()`).

Comment: I'll look into it & let you know how it goes, thanks for the suggestion